# Raspberry Pi Python GT-511C3 programming error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, arduino-uno, fingerprint, wiringpi

**[SOLVED]**
Solution in the updates below

I tried looking for the solution, and I have no idea where to ask at this point. If anyone could help me with the following.

I am connecting Raspberry Pi Zero to the [GT-511C3 fingerprint scanner](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/datasheet-sen-11792.pdf), and after getting it to respond, I constantly receive the same error code. I am not sure if problem is in my code or is in the device, and at this point I am not sure how to debug.

Here is what I do:

```
import wiringpi as wp
from struct import *

signal = pack('<BBHIH', 0x55, 0xAA, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03)
chk = sum(map(ord, list(signal)))
chk = map(chr, [chk % 256, chk / 256])
signal += chk[0] + chk[1]

wp.wiringPiSetup()
serial = wp.serialOpen('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600)
wp.serialPuts(serial, signal)

res = []
while True:
    ack = wp.serialGetchar(serial)
    if ack == -0x01:
        break
    res.append(ack)
print res
```

I am getting a response:
`['0x55', '0xaa', '0x01', '0x00', '0x0f', '0x10', '0x00', '0x00', '0x31', '0x00', '0x50', '0x01']`. The structure breakdown is described on page 6 of the [User's Manual](http://www.robotshop.com/media/files/pdf/datasheet-sen-11792.pdf), but in a nutshell it's a `NACK` response with `DEV_ERROR` comment. I am not sure what could be going wrong here.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1:**

I got the board to work on Arduino Uno, but R-Pi still has the same problem as before - receiving `NACK_DEV_ERR` all the time. I think we can safely say the problem is in the R-Pi or in my code. Will update...

**UPDATE 2:**

I think the problem was the combination of little and big endianness in the `path` routine - some of the bytes were swapped (including the checksum). I am not sure why incorrect checksum and/or command code returns `NACK_DEV_ERR`. WIll look into it more.

**UPDATE 3:**

The problem is definitely the command sequence. Apparently, wrong checksum, wrong command, wrong parameter can return `NACK_DEV_ERR` - not sure why there are no specific errors for that. Also, noticed a lot of other inconsistencies in the error codes.

If anyone interested, the working code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/zafartahirov/fingerpi).

Comment: Post your solution as an answer then accept your own answer.